# Missing Expression when Alter Default on NULL 1

Tags: oracle, default-value, alter-column

I have column in table book... named as status... i want to set default 1...

but, i tried DEFAULT 1,
`ALTER TABLE book MODIFY status DEFAULT  1`
and i insert new record... the record status is **null**

i tried to use **Default on null 1**

```
ALTER TABLE book MODIFY status DEFAULT ON NULL 1;
```

the output : **ORA-00936: missing expression**

what should i do? if i want the status value is default 1, not null when inserting new record

Comment: What is the data type of status column and what is your oracle version?

Comment: datatype = number (1), i don't know the oracle version... can you give me a advice to solve this?

Comment: `select * from v$version;`

Comment: oracle version 12c

Comment: Please share entire version string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ALTER TABLE book MODIFY status DEFAULT ON NULL 1;` statement works ([from Oracle 12.0.1 onwards](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NEWFT/chapter12101.htm#NEWFT157)):

```sql
CREATE TABLE book (
  id     INT
         GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
         PRIMARY KEY,
  status NUMBER(1)
);

ALTER TABLE book MODIFY status DEFAULT ON NULL 1;

INSERT INTO book ( status ) VALUES ( NULL );
INSERT INTO book ( status ) VALUES ( 0 );
INSERT INTO book ( status ) VALUES ( 1 );
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM book;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | STATUS
> -: | -----:
>  1 |      1
>  2 |      0
>  3 |      1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7d47093b23e5c04b107793a9e132dac4)*

---

If you are using a database version before 12.0.1 then, alternatively, you can use a trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER book__status_is_null__trg
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON book FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.status IS NULL THEN
    :new.status := 1;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8f6ebab1b7a624f8d2d4817779a3a9eb)*

Comment: ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: Still missing expression, when i execute ALTER TABLE book MODIFY status DEFAULT ON NULL 1;

Comment: @SilviaNovita Please check the db<>fiddle, as it works without errors. Also, please note the database version requirements for that syntax.